# How to render an Image coming from TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor in Fluid Typo3 9?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

I am trying to get an Image from a custom content element into my fluid template. To achieve this I am using FilesProcessor.

[custom element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOd63.png)

Here is the corresponding code snippet from my setup.typoscript:

```
tt_content {
   heiner_newcontentelement =< lib.contentElement
   heiner_newcontentelement {
      templateName = Default
      dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
      dataProcessing.10 {
         as = images
         references.fieldName = image
         references.table = tt_content
         sorting = title
         sorting.direction = descending
      }
   }
}
```

Showing what's available via f:debug-Viewhelper provides the following:

[available variables in fluid template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daddq.png)

So far, so good, what I have tried was to simply output the image in my fluid template with the following code:

```
<html data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true" xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"></html>
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="content">

  <ul class="Das ist gut">
    <f:for each="{images}" as="image">
      <f:debug>{image}</f:debug>
      <f:image image="{image}" height="250c"  width="200c"/>

    </f:for>
  </ul>
</f:section>
</html>
```

although the variable "image" in the for-each loop is not empty, the image-viewhelper wont render anything. I am so desperate :( Somebody knows whats going wrong here? A lot of thx :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, File Reference information are not always available in the fluidtemplate (see also https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Frontend.html#fluidtemplate).

What happens if you try this:

```
<ul class="Das ist gut">
  <f:for each="{images}" as="image">
    <f:debug>{image}</f:debug>
    <f:image image="{image.originalFile}" height="250c"  width="200c"/>

  </f:for>
</ul>
```